# Como puedo hacer un filtro del campo name dentro de una tabla user con nodejs

Tags: nodejs, express

soy bastante nuevo en esto me gustaria obtener todos los usuarios donde se cumpla un nombre y tengo el siguiente codigo nose si estoy avanzando yo se en php como realizarlo atraves de querys pero estoy aprendiendo con nodejs y express.

lo siguiente es mi codigo?

```
   const match = {}

        if(req.query.name){
            match.name = req.query.name 
        }
        
        try {
            await req.user.populate({
                path:'users',
                match
            }).execPopulate()
            res.send(req.user.name)
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error)
        }
```

Comment: dejame ver4 si comprendo, quieres hacer un filtro SQL?

Comment: @JackNavaRow si

Comment: y que tal si primero escribe la consulta que quieres hacer, segundo nos digas el ORM que estas usando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Termine utilizando {[Op.like]: '' } -  para traer a todos los like y utilizar mas metodos de sql.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.